# How to display even Fibonacci numbers by specifying their number?

Tags: python, fibonacci, parity

I have a function that checks Fibonacci numbers for even.

```
def fibonacci(num=4):
    fib1 = fib2 = 1
    print(0, end=' ')
    for i in range(1, num):
        fib1, fib2 = fib2, fib1 + fib2
        if (fib2 % 2) == 0:
            print(fib2, end=' ')

fibonacci()
```

I need it to output a specified number of even numbers

Example input: 4

Example output: 0 2 8 34

Comment: Your code stops after 4 numbers, not after 4 *even* numbers.

Comment: @Luuk Could you explain it more?

Comment: You are generating the first 4 numbers and then stopping. Only printing number that happen to be even.

Comment: I'm sorry. But you mean add the numbers to the range in my for loop, but leave the number in the function? Excuse me if I'm being brakes.

Comment: see the answers which are posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just go over the even ones directly:

```
def fibonacci(num=4):
    fib1, fib2 = 1, 0
    for _ in range(num):
        print(fib2, end=' ')
        fib1, fib2 = fib1 + 2*fib2, 2*fib1 + 3*fib2
```

Consider two adjacent Fibonacci numbers `a` and `b` (initially 1 and 0) and what happens when you shift the window:

```
   a     b    # odd even
   b   a+b    # even odd
 a+b  a+2b    # odd odd
a+2b 2a+3b    # odd even
```

So every third Fibonacci number is even and that last line also tells you how to shift by three steps directly.

Comment: Great! How do I achieve the same level of skill?

Comment: @lostonthecoderoad Easy, just do a lot of stuff like this for many years :-). I knew from previous experience that there's a pattern like "every third is even", then did what I showed in the bottom half of my answer to get the details.

Answer (score 3):

You could make your `fibonacci` function a generator that only yields even Fibonacci numbers, and then just pull the desired number of values from it:

```
def even_fibonacci():
    fib1, fib2 = 0, 1
    while True:
        if fib1 % 2 == 0:
            yield fib1
        fib1, fib2 = fib2, fib1 + fib2


it = even_fibonacci()
for _ in range(4):
    print(next(it))
```

prints:

```
0
2
8
34
```

Comment: great solution ;) love generators!

Comment: Can you explain what yields and what it does?

Comment: I would just swap the first line with the second and third line in the `while`. This way you can avoid thee `yield` that comes before `while`. Maybe a little more concise and elegant. Great solution.

Comment: @lostonthecoderoad `yield` allows you to define generator functions that produce an arbitrary number of values.  Instead of ending the function like `return`, a `yield` statement produces that value as the next iterator value, and then the function pauses execution until the next iteration is requested.  So in this case `even_fibonacci()` returns an iterator that simply gives you the next even Fibonacci number each time you call `next()` on it.  https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Answer (score 1):

Use while loop instead.

```
def fibonacci(count=4):
    fib1 = fib2 = 1
    i = 1
    print(0, end=' ')
    while i < count:
        fib1, fib2 = fib2, fib1 + fib2
        if (fib2 % 2) == 0:
            print(fib2, end=' ')
            i +=1

fibonacci()
```

Output:
0 2 8 34